# Spotify iOS SDK track.availableTerritories

Tags: ios, spotify

I'm using the Spotify iOS SDK in a music application I'm building. I'm having the problem where I frequently run across tracks that are not available in the US and so the SPTTrackPlayer doesn't play them. I noticed that the SPTTrack object conveniently has an availableTerritories property, so I thought "easy, I'll just check if it's available in the US, if not I'll skip it." Unfortunately, it seems that their dataset is very incomplete as many songs that are available in the US (the same URI plays in the desktop client with no complaint / in my app when I'm not weeding out tracks by availableTerritory) don't list US under availableTerritories, and many don't list any territories at all. So I'm wondering, is there another way to detect these tracks? Perhaps, something in the SPTTrackPlayer that signifies that it's unable to play the track? Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> the same URI plays in the desktop client with no complaint / in my app when I'm not weeding out tracks by availableTerritory

This is only sort of true. The desktop client automatically searches for an alternative track and plays that instead if it's not available. This is completely transparent to the user, so you won't notice it.

If you encounter a track that isn't available in the user's territory, if you do a search you're fairly likely to find another release of the same track that is available.

Comment: So just to make sure I understand what's going on in the iOS SDK, when  I give the SPTTrackPlayer a SPTTrackProvider containing a track that doesn't have the US listed as an available territory, it is replacing it with one that does behind the scenes? For example, when this track <SPTTrack: 0xbb98290>: Halo (spotify:track:3I5cWf8Zklg91QY43bkIN3) plays without complaint but doesn't have US listed, it's actually playing a different track? Thanks!

Comment: Your comment directly contradicts your question. Your question states that you can't play tracks that don't contain `US`, but your comment says you can. Which is it?

Comment: Both, and that is exactly what my question is asking because it seems you cannot distinguish which tracks are truly available in the US just by checking the availableTerritories property on the SPTTrack object. And I'm assuming that's either due to an incomplete dataset or some behind the scenes magic as your answer suggests.